# How to fading transparent with tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, tikz-fadings

I want to fill small rectangle in below cover.
My code is not fading color to background color.
Please help me correct below code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,includefoot=false,marginpar=0mm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=latest]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mauchinh}{RGB}{1,61,124}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,line join=round,line cap=round]
  \clip (current page.north west) coordinate (A) rectangle (current page.south east) coordinate (C);
  \path[fill=mauchinh] (A) rectangle (C);
  \path[bottom color=mauchinh,middle color=mauchinh,
    top color=white,
    fill opacity=0.15,blend mode=screen] (1.5,-4) rectangle +(20,-19); 
  \path[fill=white!30!mauchinh,fill opacity=0.25,blend mode=screen] (-1,-9) rectangle +(1.25,-4);
  \path[left color=mauchinh!80!white,right color=white] (-1,-9) rectangle +(19,1.25pt);
  \path[bottom color=mauchinh!80!white,top color=white] (1.5,-4) rectangle +(1.65pt,-19);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: You already set `blend mode=screen`, so you can define your gradient from any color to `transparent`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have deleted this code, It is still similar the picture.
\tikzfading[name=fade right,
  top color=transparent!50, bottom color=transparent!100]

\path[fill=white!50!mauchinh,path fading=fade right,fill opacity=0.75] (1.5,-4) rectangle +(20,-19);

Comment: This makes no sense to me. You should try something like `bottom color=transparent, top color=white, fill opacity=0.15, blend mode=screen`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fading

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{mauchinh}{RGB}{1,61,124}
\pagecolor{mauchinh}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[color=mauchinh!80!white, path fading=south] (0,0) rectangle +(20,-20);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Blue page with fading]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you take a look into the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) which has a section regarding fadings. The cover design you show is very likely copyrighted by Springer press, which is why I won't give a full answer to your question.

That said, since you already use `blend mode=screen` you can use the pseudo color `transparent` to create a fading that blends with the color of the background color, like in the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \clip (current page.north west) coordinate (A) rectangle (current page.south east) coordinate (C);
  \path[fill=blue] (A) rectangle (C);
  
  \path[top color=white, bottom color=transparent, fill opacity=0.5, blend mode=screen] (0,0) rectangle +(20,-20);
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]